# "Serious error has occurred" - null reference error

Tags: experience-editor

I'm sure we've all seen those annoying `a serious error has occurred` bars in the Experience Editor, but I have one that keeps cropping up sporadically. I'm working to isolate the scenario further to see if there's anything, I can track specifically, but in the interim I thought I'd ask about the error I'm seeing. This is in Sitecore 8.1 Update 1.

The ultimate error in the log points to a `NullReferenceException` in `\Website\sitecore\shell\client\Sitecore\ExperienceEditor\PageEditbar\PageEditbar.cshtml`

```
line 4: @Html.Sitecore().Controls().PageEditBar(Model.Rendering, Html)
```

Above that, it mentions the line in `Speak-Layout.cshtml` for the placeholder for Page.Body. I did make one modification to this file, to add in the app cache I've seen recommended (`<html data-sc-app manifest="/sitecore/shell/client/Sitecore/ExperienceEditor/Html5AppCache.ashx">`). But I haven't encountered this issue locally, and I'm using the same line.

I was curious if anyone had encountered this specific error before and found a resolution. I'm not sure if it's something in one of my renderings that's causing an issue down the line, or if it's some Sitecore quirk, etc.

Comment: Did you check this https://www.google.co.in/amp/s/learnsitecorebasics.wordpress.com/2017/01/08/solving-a-serious-error-occurred-please-contact-the-administrator-sitecore-experience-editor-error/amp/.        It has resolved similar issue for me some time back.

Comment: Any logs for when the error occurs?

Comment: Speaks "A serious error has occured" generally indicates that a rpc api call has failed. Generally these errors are retrieving item data from Sitecore, which when failing presents as a null value error. Please open up Chrome Tools -> Network Tab -> Select XHR, and then refresh the page. Look for a red ajax call. Red means it errored and post the json error from the results. This generally has allowed me to understand the real error and move past it.